# How to plot pie chart using data frame group by different range?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, matplotlib, dataframe

My Code is:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import style

df=pd.read_csv("patient1.csv")
a=df.loc[df.Age<18,['Age']]
print(a)
b=df.loc[(df.Age >= 18) & (df.Age < 60),['Age']]
print(b)
c=df.loc[df.Age>=60,['Age']]
print(c)
d=pd.concat([a,b,c],keys=["0-17","18-59","60+"])
e=d.loc[:,['Age']]
print(e)
```

The file patient1.csv contains data as:

```
Name    Surname Age
fdgf    bcbb    21
Yash    Singhvi 19
Yash    Singhvi 19
piyush  daga    20
cvcv    dfg     16
sdsd    sdsd    65
dsfef   fedf    12
rfef    fefe    70
fdgf    rgd     10
```

Actually, I want to plot pie chart of the patient of age 0-17,18-59,60+. From the code, you can see that I have separated the data frame in different ranges of age. What do I need to add to the code to plot the pie chart?

Comment: I am a bit confused - what you need plot? sum or mean for each range? Or something else?

Comment: I want to plot the ages of range 0-17,18-59,60+ on a pie chart.

Comment: I understand, but I miss logic for it. Because obviousluy need for each range only one value...

Comment: This is how I want to plot:- https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B30JxgT8aFPAVGtRYUI4NVNDSnJwdnBvWExuTTVFRmxnTjJJ

Comment: Ok, this is what I say - need 3 numbers only, for each range one.

Comment: So need sum each range?

Comment: You can see that in csv file I have data of ages which I have divided in 3 data frame a,b,c of range 0-17,18-59,60+ respectively. So can I plot pie chart with this divide data frame or there is another way to plot?

Comment: I don't need sum. I need the average in percentage on one pie chart.

Comment: There is many other ways for plot, check [this](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/visualization.html)

Comment: So can you just give me code on my problem to plot on ranges of age 0-17,18-59,60+

Comment: There is logic problem - try `e.plot.pie(subplots=True)` - Are you sure it need?

Comment: Actually, i know the syntax to plot the pie chart but the problem is that I don't know how to plot on range.

Comment: Yes, and this is problem. Plot multiple values in pie for one range have no sense. Need one scalar value for each range like `0-17 -> 10`, `"18-59" -> 50` and `60+ -> 5`.

Comment: and your picture is exactly it - [pic](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B30JxgT8aFPAVGtRYUI4NVNDSnJwdnBvWExuTTVFRmxnTjJJ)

Comment: okay here in the csv file there are 9 members in which 3 are from 0-17, 4 are from 18-59 and 2 are from 60 above. So according to their count, I need to plot the pie chart.

Comment: It is much better, give me some time.

Comment: Sorry for all the misunderstanding.

Answer (score 13):

You need [`cut`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.cut.html) for create `range`s first. Then [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html), aggregate [`size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html) and reshape by [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html).

Last use [`DataFrame.plot.pie`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.pie.html):

```
df['bins'] = pd.cut(df['Age'],bins=[0,17,59,120], labels=["0-17","18-59","60+"])
df = df.groupby(['Age', 'bins']).size().unstack(fill_value=0)
print (df)
bins  0-17  18-59  60+
Age                   
10       1      0    0
12       1      0    0
16       1      0    0
19       0      2    0
20       0      1    0
21       0      1    0
65       0      0    1
70       0      0    1

df.plot.pie(subplots=True,figsize=(8, 3))
```

[image: graph]

EDIT:

```
a = df.groupby('bins').size()
#a = df['bins'].value_counts()
print (a)
bins
0-17     3
18-59    4
60+      2
dtype: int64

a.plot.pie(figsize=(4,4))
```

[image: graph]

Comment: actually that was the data from a single file and those are the three labels i.e. 0-17, 18-59, 60+ , not three different plots . so how could you get that i need only a single pie chart

Comment: there are 3 ranges, so need 3 graphs. Or something mising?

Comment: Maybe need  `df.groupby(['Age']).size().plot.pie()` - but there is no information about bins.

Comment: Hmmm, maybe the best will be if try create this graph in excel and post picture, because it seems we dont understand each other.

Comment: I need only one pie chart which contains section of 0-17,18-59,60+.

Comment: Do you need `df.groupby('bins').size().plot.pie()` ?

Comment: I add it to answer.

Comment: I didn't understand the concept of bins.

Comment: Maybe [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reshaping.html#tiling) it is explained better. But it simple add label by range - it is faster and more flexible.

Comment: and check [this](https://chrisalbon.com/python/pandas_binning_data.html)